# SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message

Tags: java, ssl, tibco, opensaml

I'm using:

```
not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.9.jar
opensaml-2.3.1.jar
```

I'm getting the following error in my logs:

```
SSLException: Received fatal alert: unexpected_message
```

Turning on SSLDebug gives the following:

```
TP-Processor2, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
TP-Processor2, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, unexpected_message
TP-Processor2, called closeSocket()
TP-Processor2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert:  unexpected_message
%% Client cached [Session-40, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
%% Try resuming [Session-40, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5] from port 2903
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
```

The behaviour is that SSL connections work for five minutes - and then they fail with the message above. My guess is that this is an SSL session cache issue.

Has anyone resolved this?

Comment: to quote the spec: "unexpected_message... is always fatal and should never be observed in communication between proper implementations."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out that bouncy-castle (a jar dependency of opensaml) adds a bunch of extra ciphers into the SSL negotiation. The TIBCO server has a spew at these extra ciphers. Rolling back the Bouncy Castle Jar to 1.3.5 (pre-elliptic SLL Ciphers) solved this issue.